# BLE Disconnect Callback from SamsungGalxy S6 and J7

Tags: android

I am trying to connect external BLE devices(Audio speaker) from SamsungGalaxy S6 and J7 phone. But randomaly getting disconnect callabck for BLE device 
(audio speaker) in our codebase from SamsungGalaxy S6/J7.Our observation is this disconnect callback coming from Phone OS.

Please find below our code snippet.

Code

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback connectionCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {

            // Devices is Connect

        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {

           // Disconnect call ocuur frequently from Phone(Samsung s6/s7). No such call should come from other phone. 

        }
    }
```

Why Samsung Galaxy S6/J7 send BLE disconnect callback onConnectionStateChange()?

Comment: If you look around in places like [this one](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/540579-bluetooth-keeps-disconnecting.html) it is not uncommon to have these kind of problems. I'd suggest you add more info into your question, e.g. Android version, stuff that you have investigated, environment in which you've been testing. Thanks.

Comment: I used  Android Version :  Above 5.0
BLE Version : 4.1